# Viewing Task information not working .NET 5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-5, intellitrace

I am working on a .NET 5 WPF app, and I am trying to view task information via the *Debug->Windows->Tasks* and the *Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks* pane.

However, the Tasks pane is completly blank, and the Parallel Stacks pane gives the following error:

`Viewing Task information for .NET Core 2.1/2.2 is not supported for live processes. You can either re-target a newer version of the runtime, or save a minidump and view task information for your application.`

This is very strange, since the application is targetting .NET 5. This is also confirmed by running `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.TargetFrameworkName` while the application is running, which returns ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0".

This happens for both x64 and x86 platform targets. This issue has also been reproduced on two different systems.

The TFM for the startup application is `net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0`.

.NET SDK: 5.0.101
Runtime: 5.0.1
Visual Studio: 16.8.3

Edit:
Turns out this is easily reproducable, and affects all projects that target `net5.0-windows*`. Therefore, please refer to my issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15055) and [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-view-Task-or-parallel-stacks-i/1293379) instead.

Comment: Hmm, works fine in .netcore 3.1 (not in 2.2) in VS version 16.4.1.  Might be work-in-progress, but start by creating the opposite of a "live process" with Debug > Break All.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your answer. After digging around some more, it turns out this is a .NET 5 spesific issue. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15055) featuring better repro steps.